# installing Java 7 or above on OSx Mavericks

Tags: java, macos, android-studio, java-8

Just now I installed java 8 required for Android Studio(7 or version above), hoping after install my java version will automatically pointing to the latest version but but I think it is just not pointing it is also not there.

```
$:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions$ ll
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 Jan  5  2014 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 root  wheel  408 Feb 11  2015 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jan  5  2014 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jan  5  2014 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jan  5  2014 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jan  5  2014 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jan  5  2014 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jan  5  2014 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  272 Jan  6  2014 A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 Jan  5  2014 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   59 Jan  5  2014 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
```

This is all I have so where did new java 8 version got installed to ? how do I manually update paths ?

doing `which java` in shell points to /usr/bin/java which is further symlink to `/usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`

I need a path to put here in image below:
[image: Android Studio Java 7 + install path]

Comment: I personally use `jEnv`. You might want to take a look into. - http://www.jenv.be/ and the github repository https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv.

Comment: Well, @AlexisC. even though if you install using jenv, you have add it using `jenv add path/to/Java/8/Home/Folder/`  but I do not know where it is installed, when I tried to install the older version i.e. 7, i got this message 

`You are trying to install Java 7 Update 80, however Java 8 Update 65 build 17 is already installed.
Visit java.com/newerversionexists for more information.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer what I was looking for,

so its install at this path: `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/`

`echo 'export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

by now you open a new shell you should get `java -fullversion` result in 
java full version "1.8.0_66-b17"

follow below steps to add to jenv/ or should I say add via jenv.

however you cannot add `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` to jenv.

to add to jenv I created a symlink in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions` using

`sudo ln -s  /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/ 1.8`

and then did `jenv add /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.8/Home/`
oracle64-1.8.0.66 added

```
1.8.0.66 added
1.8 added
```